# Only send values that have changed in formik onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a small table of data that is pre-filled by an api call on page load. Each row in the table has a facility name and an `Enabled` value which comes from the api call. If `Enabled` == true the checkbox is shown as checked.

I have a couple checkboxes that are grayed out because of a condition in which it cannot be changed at all so there's a readOnly attribute on the field.

Onto my question, for brevity I condensed the list of facilities shown in the table, but in reality there could be `X` amount of facilities. In my `onSubmit` function I only want to send the facility name and `enabled` value if they have been selected/deselected instead of sending the entire list every time submit is pressed.

Ideally I want the shape of the data sent to look like so:

```
{
    facilityName: "Backup Restore",
    enabled: true
}
```

Now, I have been able to isolate JUST the `facilityName` and `enabled` value but I cannot figure out to only include the values that have been changed in the form. Like I said above, not every single facility name and enabled key/value should be sent every time submit is pressed just the ones that have been changed.

This is what I currently have(and can be seen in the sandbox below) in my onSubmit function

```
         <Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={{
            facilities: loggingFacilities
          }}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {

            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            try {

              setLoggingFacilities(values.facilities);
              const valuesToSend = values.facilities.map(facility => {
                return {
                  key: facility.facilityName,
                  value: facility.enabled
                };
              });
              .....
```

I have a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/logging-table-l2rut)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the second param of your [`onSubmit`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag-void-promise-any) callback, you can access `props`, so you could diff `values` against `props.initialValues` or however you have called the prop you use to initialize the form.

Actually, that's the [suggestion from Jared Palmer](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/215):

> You can compare `initialValues` and values within `handleSubmit` / `onSubmit`.

Using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it would look something like this:

```
onSubmit={async (values, { props, setSubmitting }) => {

  // Let's assume this has the same format as `values.facilities`:
  const { initialValues } = props;

  try {
    setLoggingFacilities(values.facilities);

    const valuesToSend = values.facilities.filter((facility, i) => {
      // Let's send only those that have just been disabled or enabled:
      return facility.enabled !== initialValues[i].enabled;
    }).map((facility) => ({
      key: facility.facilityName,
      value: facility.enabled
    }));

    // ...

  } catch(err) { ... }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, looking into the proposed solution. It looks like there's an issue with the filter function being undefined.

Comment: This will only work if the number of facilities is always the same because you are using the index `i` from `values.facilities` to access `initialValues[i]` and it's assuming there are not empty elements in those arrays. If the user can add or remove facilities, then you need to change that logic. You could use `facilityName` to create a map of `facilityName` - `enabled` and then diff these 2 objects (the one from `initialValues` and the one from `values`) to get the ones that have changed, the ones that have been removed and the ones that have been created.

Comment: The number of `facilities` never changes. You cannot add or remove them. The only thing the user can do is toggle the `Enabled` value of the facility.

Comment: Then try checking if any of those two arrays have empty items. If that's the case, this should fix it: `facility && initialValues[i] && facility.enabled !== initialValues[i].enabled`.

Comment: `const { initialValues } = props;` `initialValues` is still undefined

Comment: @DJ2 That's the prop you use to initialize the form, it might be called something else in your case.

Comment: It's definitely still `initialValues`

Comment: Maybe you are setting it and then changing its value? The form will not change unless `enableReinitialize` is `true`, but the code above won't work as it will receive the current value. You need to debug your code and see where/when that value is being lost.

Comment: `initialValues` and `values` diverge when a checkbox is unchecked/checked. The `initialValues` come from an api request so `enableReinitialize` is needed to populate the `initialValues` from the received data

Comment: Welp I think I found the solution. Instead of using `initialValues[i]`, I can use the state value of `loggingFacilities` instead. It holds the true original data, whereas `initialValues` never did due to `enableReinitialize`

Comment: Maybe ```dirty``` can be used here somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const getChangedValues = (values, initialValues) => {
  return Object
    .entries(values)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      const hasChanged = initialValues[key] !== value

      if (hasChanged) {
        acc[key] = value
      }

      return acc
    }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

addition to the answer of randomKek (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66729194/878055)

Here is the typescript version of his function

```js
const getChangedValues = <T extends Record<string, any>>(values: T, initialValues: T) => {
  return Object.entries(values).reduce((acc: Partial<T>, [key, value]) => {
    const hasChanged = initialValues[key as keyof T] !== value;

    if (hasChanged) {
      acc[key as keyof T] = value;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm arriving later to this issue but I think you can use [dirty](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#dirty-boolean) flag. It appears to do the deep comparing with initial values for you. And will complement nicely with @Dazinger approach.

> dirty: boolean
> Returns true if values are not deeply equal from initial values, false otherwise. dirty is a readonly computed property and should not be mutated directly.

Comment: `dirty` returns `boolean` indicator rather than values which are modified.