# How to get Formik initialValues when submitting?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm new to Formik and not sure how to access the `initialValues` in my submit handler in order to compare it with `values` before submitting.

If someone could show how this is done in the basic Formik example below I'd be happy.

```
const Basic = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
        // GET initialValues HERE... 
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <Field id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />

        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <Field
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="jane@acme.com"
          type="email"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Basic />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I know there are a few threads out there explaining how to do it with HOCs etc. , like https://medium.com/@MelkorNemesis/how-to-check-if-formik-values-have-changed-on-submit-2c6ee89992ec but my React knowledge is to low to translate this into the basic function above. FWIW I also think it would be beneficial to have this as an example in the Formik docs, seems like a pretty common use case.

Comment: I found this answer is pretty close to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619976/5972355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an object inside your component and pass it to Formik *initialValues* prop.

```
const Basic = () => {
  const initialValues = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          // compare initialValues and values here
        }}
      >
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="jane@acme.com"
            type="email"
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Basic />, document.getElementById('root'));
```