# Is it possible to track that the data in the field has changed Formik

Tags: reactjs, events, formik

Does `Formik` have a general event of the `onChange` type, for example, `onSubmit`, so that it is possible to check whether the field has been changed or not because checking for data changes in the field itself does not suit me, I need a general solution.

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
          name: '',
          phone: '',
          email: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onChange={({values}) => {
          ...
        }}
      >
```

I want to perform some operations when data changes in fields, for example, I want to do such an operation that will add a set timeout of 60 seconds to the conditional "onChange" of the Formik, and if the user stops, I will submit the form to the server, the problem is because I need an event not for form validation but for changing one of the fields, and I don't want to insert this handler in each of the fields for the input "onChange" event because I have more than 30 fields of different types, I want to track the change conditional `setFieldValue` Formik.

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619976/1481519

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only send values that have changed in formik onSubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619890/only-send-values-that-have-changed-in-formik-onsubmit)

Comment: @MaheshSamudra In fact, yes, it may make sense for me, but if I want to do some operations when maintaining data, for example, I want to make such a debounce that will add a set timeout of 60 seconds to the conditional "onChange" and if the user stops, I I will send the form to the server, the problem is that I need an event not to confirm the form, but to change one of the fields, and I don't want to push this handler into each of the fields for the "onChange" event, because I have more than 30 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather elegant solution to my problem and it's actually what I needed, I had to google more carefully so I came across this wonderful [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-listen-to-formik-onchange-event-in-react-df00c4d09be) that solved my problem.

The solution is as follows to create an observer component and insert it inside *hoc Formik* in any place, and inside this component should use `useFormikContext` and pass the already necessary data.

Observer component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik'

const FormikValueObserver = ({ onChange }) => {
  const { values, initialValues } = useFormikContext()

  useEffect(() => onChange({values, initialValues}), [values, initialValues, onChange])

  return null
}

export default FormikValueObserver
```

Using:

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  {({..., handleSubmit}) => (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormikValueObserver onChange={(values, initialValues) => {
                console.log("This will work on changing any value in the field", values)
         }} />
         ...
     </form>
  )}
</Formik>
```